# A curious class of polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

In connection with some calculations involving generating functions I have encounetered the following family of polynomials

$$  p_{k,N}(x) = \sum_{0<n_1<n_2<\ldots<n_k<N} \prod_{i=1}^k (x-n_i),$$

and I was wondering whether anyone knows of a compact way of expressing these using binomials and perhaps some nice functions in the $n_i$. More generally I would be interested in knowing whether these polynomials have a name and are part of a larger theory.

Hope some of you might know the answer to some of these questions.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomials can be expressed as

$$\begin{align}p_{k,N}(x) &= \frac{1}{(N-1-k)!} \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{N-1-k} \,\prod_{m=1}^{N-1} (x-m) \\&= \frac{1}{(N-1-k)!} \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{N-1-k} (x-N+1)^{(N-1)},\end{align}$$

where $a^{(b)}$ is the [rising factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RisingFactorial.html).  By formula $(9)$ on [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheFirstKind.html) we can rewrite this as

$$p_{k,N}(x) = \frac{1}{(N-1-k)!} \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{N-1-k} \,\sum_{m=0}^{N-1} s(N-1,m)(x-1)^m,$$

where $s(a,b)$ is a Stirling number of the first kind.